# Is it possible to compress an image that has been converted from base64 string to binary?

Tags: base64, compression, image-compression, image-upload, imagemin

I have an app that should create a thumbnail from large images. So I need to compress the image and for that I'm using the package *imagemin*.

I get the input from the user as a base64 string, and then on my server, I convert it using Buffer.from(*base64string*, "base64").

The issue is that the output from *imagemin* is not compressed at all. No error is thrown, but the image is not compressed. Although it works perfectly when I pass untouched binary data *(such as from an image.jpg file)*, it *seems* to not be possible to use binary data that has been converted **from** base64 strings.

**my code:**

```
const imagemin = require("imagemin");
const imageminJpegtran = require("imagemin-jpegtran");
const imageminMozjpeg = require("imagemin-mozjpeg");
const imageminPngquant = require("imagemin-pngquant");
const fs = require("fs");

const myPic = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile("/image.txt", (err, data) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      resolve(Buffer.from(data, "base64"));
    });
  });
};

const waitMyPic = async () => {
  const picBuff = await myPic();
  return picBuff;
};

waitMyPic().then((res) => {
  console.log("Original File Size: " + Math.round(res.length / 1024));

  const compressImg = async (res) => {
    const files = await imagemin.buffer(res, {
      plugins: [
        imageminJpegtran(),
        imageminMozjpeg({
          quality: [10],
        }),
        imageminPngquant({ quality: [0.1, 0.12] }),
      ],
    });
    return files;
  };
  compressImg(res).then((data) => {
    console.log("Compressed File Size: " + Math.round(res.length / 1024));
    fs.writeFile("/image2.txt", data, (err, data) => {
      if (err) throw err;
    });
  });
});
```

> note that in this code I'm reading a .txt file that has the base64
> string of an image, and then I'm converting it to binary so I can use
> it in the *imagemin* function. This is for testing only, in the real
> situation the base64 strings would be served by the user and sent to
> the server through POST requests.

Any thoughts on this?

I'm not attached to *imagemin* at all, I could use another solution if someone points out a better approach. All I want to do is to compress an image as much as I can without making it unrecognizable, so I can create thumbnails that will be used in the blog "posts catalog".

Answer (score 0):

Sure just do pass the result from `Buffer.from(data, 'base64')` as the argument to `imagemin.buffer(result,` . Make sure that data is just the base64 data itself and does not include the metadata i.e. `"data:image/png;base64,"`

Answer (score 0):

Yup with the help imageminMozjpeg plugin I able to reduce the size by 1/10 example code below

```
import imagemin from "imagemin";
import imageminMozjpeg from "imagemin-mozjpeg";
const ogBuffer = Buffer.from(base64String, "base64");
const buffer = await imagemin.buffer(ogBuffer, {
  plugins: [imageminMozjpeg({ quality: 50 })],
});
```